# React Lazyload as soon as page interacted with

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

I'm building a React site which uses live chat and am using the react-livechat package. I've paired this up with the react-lazyload plugin to try to prevent it from adversely affect page load times.

I'm now trying to work out a way to load the livechat component in as soon as the page is interacted with. Currently it only renders when the page is scrolled to within a set distance of the component which by default is the footer of the page. This does prevent the page load being impacted but requires a user to scroll a certain distance before the component loads. Ideally it would load form any interaction with the page.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import LiveChat from 'react-livechat';
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload';

class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        ...
        <LazyLoad once>
          <LiveChat license={'xxxxxx'} />
        </LazyLoad>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this behavior with a workaround and loading the component after a certain period of time. I found that 10 seconds worked well to ensure even on mobile everything had entirely rendered.

```js
// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LazyLiveChat from './components/utils/lazyLiveChat';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { loadLiveChat: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({loadLiveChat: true}), 10000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        ...
        <LazyLiveChat loadChat={this.state.loadLiveChat} />
        ...
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default App;

// lazyLiveChat.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LiveChat from 'react-livechat';

class LazyLiveChat extends Component {

  render() {
    if (this.props.loadChat) {
      return (
        <LiveChat license={xxxxxx} />
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}

export default LazyLiveChat;
```